# How to shade row based on change of value using Pandas and export to Excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to see if there is a way to highlight/shade rows based on alternating group values. Let's say there is a column of the following values:

[image]

I want all the 1132 shaded, then the 3002 unshaded, and then 3012 shaded, and so and so forth.

I found some ways of doing this through Excel, but wasn't sure how to apply this using Pandas which is what I'm using to sort and filter this data in the first place. It would be nice to do everything within one place.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
df
    col
0  1132
1  1132
2  3002
3  3002
4  3002
5  3012
6  3012
```

#### Code

```
def color(s):
    m = s != s.shift()
    m = m.cumsum() % 2 == 1 # alternate styles
    return np.where(m, 'background-color: blue', 'background-color: red')

styled = df.style.apply(color, subset=['col'])
styled.to_excel('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

#### Working

- Compare current and prev rows to identify change
- Use cumsum to  create counter to identify different groups
- Modulo divide the counter by 2 to create a boolean mask for alternate shade

#### Result

[image]